# Same Total for current and 3 future weeks instead of Running Total

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi There I have a bit of a interesting request. I have a running total by partition for current row and 3 rows below. It works fine but I want the same total for the partition instead of a running total. E.g for the first four rows the four_weeks_cover should be 14 and for the next 4 rows the total should be 12 which is the total of the four rows.

```
Here is my sample Result

Item_No Week_Starting_Monday    Cover_Weeks Four_Weeks_Cover
6-KDDDORF   20201012    3   14
6-KDDDORF   20201019    2   12
6-KDDDORF   20201026    5   12
6-KDDDORF   20201102    4   11
6-KDDDORF   20201109    1   12
6-KDDDORF   20201116    2   11
6-KDDDORF   20201123    4   9
6-KDDDORF   20201130    5   5
```

What I want the result to be:
**

```
Item_No Week_Starting_Monday    Cover_Weeks Four_Weeks_Cover
6-KDDDORF   20201012    3   14
6-KDDDORF   20201019    2   14
6-KDDDORF   20201026    5   14
6-KDDDORF   20201102    4   14
6-KDDDORF   20201109    1   12
6-KDDDORF   20201116    2   12
6-KDDDORF   20201123    4   12
6-KDDDORF   20201130    5   12
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
                *, SUM (Cover_Weeks) OVER (PARTITION BY [Item_No] ORDER BY [Week_Starting_Monday] ROWS BETWEEN current row and 3 following) AS Four_Weeks_Cover
FROM
Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a row number and divide by 4 to gets a grouping.  Then sum within the grouping:

```
SELECT t.*,
        SUM(Cover_Weeks) OVER (PARTITION BY Item_No, (seqnum - 1) / 4)  AS Four_Weeks_Cover
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_No ORDER BY Week_Starting_Monday) - 1 as seqnum
      FROM Table_Name t
     ) t;
```